# what's the difference between declaring object inside data() and inside created() in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to know what is the difference in VueJs between these two types of declaration :

```
data() {
    return {
        foo = 'bar'
    }
}
```

and this :

```
created() {

    this.foo = 'bar'
}
```

I know that I an access both using 'this' in  or in methods. 
Also, if the returned object in data() is saved in "memory" of the component, where does the object declared in created() is saved? 
are they in different scopes? 
Also, I know that to fetch data, the fetcher lands in created() and then updates the data object, but this question is specifically about the differences between the two ways of declarations i mentioned 
Is there any differences in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about vue `data` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data).

> Vue will recursively convert its ($data) properties into getter/setters to make it “reactive”..

```
created() {
    this.foo = 'bar'
}
```

Declaring like above, you won't be able to watch the attributes.
You can check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/x1sgv6ec/) example out, watch function isn't fired with the attribute being not defined in `data()`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, is there any specific user-case where I must (or considered good practice) to use non reactive variables?

Comment: I think it's a better practice to put properties into where they belong (`props`, `data` or `computed`)